# SQLLite system tables

Tags: sqlite

I have created a new SQLLite database via a PHP script for a quick MVP.

In comparing the database structure with a file that has been passed to me I can appreciate the absence of some sys/* tables that are missing from my new database.
Differences have been noticed using [DB Browser for SQLLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/)

I've been reading through the SQLLite documentation and it seems like there is only one sys table - sysmaster - that can implicitly be queried.

So my question is, what are these other tables like sys/version or stuff like that? 
Are they needed? Do they refer to a previous version of SQLite (e.g. v2)?

Thanks

Comment: Whoever or whatever created the database you're looking at made those tables. Internal sqlite tables start with `sqlite_`.

Answer (score 2):

> In comparing the database structure with a file that has been passed
>   to me I can appreciate the absence of some sys/* tables that are
>   missing from my new database.

**sys** tables are not SQLite system tables and are thus user defined tables.

> I've been reading through the SQLLite documentation and it seems like
>   there is only one sys table - sysmaster - that can implicitly be
>   queried.

All SQLite system tables start with **sqlite_**

The only one that must exist is **sqlite_master**, this is database's schema.

Others may exist as per :-

**sqlite_sequence** will exist if any table includes the AUTOINCREMENT keyword (which is restricted to only being used for an alias of the rowid column).

**sqlite_statn** (where n is a numeric 1-4) are created when an ANALYZE is run.

- stat2-4 are dependant upon compilation options, and are typically not prsent after an ANALAYZE.

**sqlite_autoindex_***??? are created when UNIQUE and PRIMARY KEY constraints are used BUT NOT for an alias of the **rowid**

SQLite system tables are all implicitly accessed, all can also be accessed and some can even be changed (at your own risk).

**sqlite_master** cannot be changed e.g. trying to run :-

```
INSERT INTO sqlite_master VALUES('table','ooops','ooops','CREATE TABLE ooops (COL1 TEXT)');
```

results in :-

```
INSERT INTO sqlite_master VALUES('table','ooops','ooops','CREATE TABLE ooops (COL1 TEXT)')
> table sqlite_master may not be modified
> Time: 0s
```

Perhaps consider the following :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable1;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable1 (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, -- autoincrement results in sqlite_sequence being created
    COL1 TEXT UNIQUE -- UNIQUE results in an sqlite_autoindex table being created
    );
ANALYZE; -- will result in sqlite_stat1 being created
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master; -- RESULT1
SELECT * FROM sqlite_stat1; -- RESULT2
SELECT * FROM sqlite_sequence; -- RESULT3
INSERT INTO mytable1 (COL1) VALUES ('A'),('B'),('C'); -- will result in sqlite_sequence being updated
SELECT * FROM sqlite_sequence; -- RESULT4
UPDATE sqlite_sequence SET seq = 100 WHERE name = 'mytable1'; -- naughty
INSERT INTO mytable1 (COL1) VALUES ('X'),('Y'),('Z');
SELECT * FROM sqlite_sequence; -- RESULT5
SELECT * FROM mytable1; -- RESULT6
```

The results from the queries are :-

### Result 1

[image]

i.e Sqlite tables **sqlite_stat1**, **sqlite_sequence** and **sqlite_autoindex_mytable1_1** have been created.

### Result 2

[image]

i.e. **sqlite_stat1** is empty (nothing to ANALYZE)

### Result 3

[image]

i.e. **sqlite_sequence** is empty (no rows have been inserted into mytable1)

### Result 4

After insert 3 rows into mytable1 **sqlite_sequence** has a row for mytable1 the seq value is 3 (the last rowid inserted).

[image]

### Result 5

After updating the seq value too 100 another 3 rows are added to mytable1 the seq number has increased to 103

[image]

### Result 6

and **mytable** has the expected 6 rows BUT the **id** (alias of the rowid column) has jumped after 3 to 100 (because **sqlite_sequence** was altered) :-

[image]

> So my question is, what are these other tables like sys/version or
>   stuff like that? Are they needed? Do they refer to a previous version
>   of SQLite (e.g. v2)?

Hopefully the above has answered most. But perhaps as a summary, let SQLite manage it's system tables. You may wish to read [Database File Format - 2.6.1. Internal Schema Objects](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html#internal_schema_objects) up to Section 3.

Comment: Hey @MikeT thanks for your effort in putting the above together. Really useful. In digging more, I found a sort of an answer. Apparently those tables must have been added, or in any case are necessary for a standalone CRUD php API - https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api. Without those tables I was not able to query the database from a local script that has been put together by another dev. Hadn't a change to fully debut, but this sounds a bit strange. Have you had a chance to use the above?

Comment: @AndreaMoro Re *a chance to use the above*; If you mean php-crud-ap1. No, I answered solely from an SQLite perspective.